# Elasticsearch with nested AND/OR query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm struggling with writing an elastic search query with multiple AND/OR conditions.

It basically comes to the following logic:
`cond1 && (cond2 || cond3 || cond4)`

As mentioned in the [docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/query-dsl-bool-query.html), a document is considered a match if it satisfies only the must clause. The should clauses in this case act as a boost i.e. if a document matches one or more of the should clauses in addition to the must clause, then it will have a higher relevancy score, assuming that cond2, cond3 and cond4 are queries that calculate a relevancy score.

The problem is that I only want documents that also match at least one of the OR conditions.

Note that I'm running ES6.3. I've also tried [Multiword queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/match-multi-word.html) but these results are also wrong.

Adding [boost](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-boost.html) doesn't seem to affect the results, I have results that only match the first condition.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                    "term": {
                        "event.keyword": {
                            "value": "webhook.trigger"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "should": [
                {
                    "match": {
                        "metaData.webhook.title": "My Example Title 1"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "match": {
                        "metaData.webhook.title": "Testing"
                    }
                },
{
                    "match": {
                        "metaData.webhook.url": "myurl.com"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `should` query works like a **OR** only if there is not a `must` query. In your case you should wrap the `should` query in another `bool` query.

````
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "event.keyword": {
                            "value": "webhook.trigger"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "metaData.webhook.title": "My Example Title 1"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "metaData.webhook.title": "Testing"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "metaData.webhook.url": "myurl.com"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}```
````